# Air plane mode schedule

Tags: iphone, ios, shortcut, airplane-mode

Is there any way to schedule airplane mode in iPhone?
I create an automation in shortcut
But it’s send me a notification and I should to run that manually and it won’t work automatically.
Is there any way!?

Comment: Siri Shortcuts?

Answer (score 1):

> Hey Siri, turn on airplane mode.

That automates turning on airplane mode very well for me. I hope this meets your needs based on the requirements listed.

Comment: Thanks for answer.But I want to turn off it automatically.For example when I’m in sleep

Comment: Aah, do not disturb or sleep timer don’t seem to kick this off. Interesting request. I’ll edit my post if I can figure your additional clarification.

Comment: For example, My friend should call me at 7:00AM.and my iphone is in airplane mode during night.so I want to turning off airplane mode automatically to hear his call

Comment: On a related note, I've been trying to use the Shortcuts app to automate tasks similar to this, and found the conditions that can be evaluated is quite limited.  If you find something, I would love to learn what can be done with scenarios like this!

Answer (score 1):

The **shortcots app** is very *powerful* in this case. The *automation* can be **activated/deactivated**. Automation triggers are broken up into three categories: Events, Travel, and Settings. Each trigger is also either what I call "active" or "passive" in nature. An active trigger is one that is the result of a user's deliberate action, like plugging your iPhone into your CarPlay-enabled vehicle or tapping an NFC tag. At some point, you deliberately did something to or with your iPhone to start your automation.

A passive trigger, like the time of day or arriving at or leaving a location, is one where you're not actively doing something to or with your phone. While you might leave a location with your iPhone in your pocket, for instance, your phone is passive at that moment. Ironically, these automations with this type of trigger ultimately require your active consent to run. When their trigger is activated, you'll get a notification. Tapping that notification will show you a "Run" button. Tap that, and your automation will run.

In my example, I have activate the *Automation*:

[image]

Then you can as example automate to turn off the air plan mode by ringing the alarm clock. So if your alarm is ringing and you stop the alarm, the air plan mode will turn off. In order for this to work without confirmation after the alarm clock stopping, the "Ask Before Running" setting must be deactivated for this shortcut. If this is not deactivated, after your alarm clock is stopping, you will asked, if you will turn off the air plan mode. But this is not desirable.

[image]

So every time when a alarm rings and you stop them, the air plan mode will turn off and the iPhone will connect to the internet.

Comment: Thanks a lot.but I don’t want to alarm.I want air plane mode will be turn off automatically at a time in a day. Can I create this shortcut?

Comment: Yes of course, you must add a "New Automation" in *Shurtcuts*, then select "Time of Day" (the top one by *Events*) and choose a time, on which weekday it should repeat and then add the **action** where to perform at this choosen moment. "Add Action", search "Set Airplan Mode" and then click off.

Comment: look at this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/Tg97nAg86V4)

Comment: This is the correct answer (just tested it out), but I think it can be better written to specifically show how to create the automation with respect to the question itself.  the answer is a bit broad.

Comment: @SwissCodeMen but this way isn’t automatic.because I should to run that manually.

Comment: You must just manually create and start the automation and if you have start it, it would run automatically... On every choosen day, at the selected time. You can also make for everyday a own automation, when you will that the automation is executed at different times...